# Services on balock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

Can i perform services on lock screen in andriod . like i want to send email  or want to record voice by firing events automatically through coding while my Mobile screen is still locked . if yes then how ?
need your help . thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to register a service to listen to phone lock and phone unlock, so in your `manifest.xml`:

```
    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="receiver.lockScreenReeiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

then, create a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle this events:

```
public class lockScreenReeiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
           //TODO do whatever you want when the screen is locked(e.g  send email, record voice, ...etc)
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
           //TODO do whatever you want when the screen is unlocked
        }
    }

}
```